# connect firebase firestore to javascript backend

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm running this code to get timetable updates, I am wondering if there's a way that I can connect this script to my firebase firestore to get the course code? (EPL1 in this case), is this possible or does it have to be in the react native project? It won't let me combine this code with the RN projevt because it can't use node modules os api , so i'm thinkin of just writing the data to a json file if i can get the code from firestore. Is it possible? I have a users collection in firestore with name,coursecode, email etc.

```
let OpenTimetable = require('../index.js')

OpenTimetable.FetchTimetable('EPL1', 'Friday', new Date(2021, 02, 12))
.then(Data => {
    console.log(Data)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Why you cant combine firestore with your code? Don't understand your question

Comment: @Stevetro I'm not sure how i can import firestore into the code i've put above because when i import firebase there's still an error so then i put type: "module" into package.json and then it says require is then invalid, so I'm not sure whats wrong. thank you:)

Comment: you want to use this code in your backend, like nodejs / express or something? Then you could use firebase-admin to retrive the data from firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup